# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gather_keys_oauth2'

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to create a Python Script to get my hands on my Fitbit data so that I can alternately integrate it with another API. I have been following the instruction on this website https://towardsdatascience.com/collect-your-own-fitbit-data-with-python-ff145fa10873

I have used pip to install Fitbit, Pandas, DateTime and also Oauth. To install OAuth I used the following:
pip install oauth -t fitbitAPI

It installed without any issue.

I put the following lines into my Python Script:

```
import fitbit
import gather_keys_oauth2 as Oauth2
import pandas as pd
import datetime
```

When I test the script I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fitbitAPI.py", line 2, in <module>
import gather_keys_oauth2 as Oauth2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gather_keys_oauth2'
```

I spent hours searching the web but have not been able to find anything that's been helpful. Any ideas? Is there another version or way that I need to install OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to resolve the error:

- Download the `fitbit` package as described (https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit).
- After you install `fitbit` as described, navigate to the newly created folder `\Lib\site-packages\fitbit`
- Copy and paste the `gather_keys_oauth2.py` file into the `fitbit` folder
- Then you can `from fitbit import gather_keys_oauth2 as Oauth2`

Comment: Also make sure to:  1) use Python 3, 2) run `pip install fitbit` and 3) run `pip install cherrypy`

Answer (score 1):

One clarification on Jacob Miller's solutions:

> Copy and paste the gather_keys_oauth2.py file into the fitbit folder
> copy gather_keys_oauth2.py into the Lib/site-packages folder if the above still results in the not found error.

And, I installed cherrypy (required by gather_keys_oauth2.py) using the Anaconda Navigator:
[screen shot from Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLfBi.jpg)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to source the module from [orcasgit](https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit). You can download the python script [here](https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/blob/master/gather_keys_oauth2.py) and stick it in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and solved by updating my environment and making sure I was using python3. I had activated the wrong environment with the `conda activate environmentname` command, and so the notebook was throwing this same error.

- Install Anaconda-Navigator
- Create a new environment with the Anaconda-Navigator tool
- Make sure you are using Python 3.x in this new environment
- Install cherrpy using the Anaconda-Navigator tool
- When you start-up terminal and navigate to the directory of your app, you'll activate your environment with `conda activate environmentname` and then start up your notebook `jupyter notebook`. This error should disappear.

**Note:** there may be some additional packages you need to install. Keep using the anaconda navigator to continue installing the packages; the error messages coming off the notebook will guide you to install the right packages.